# Amazon Web Services: NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials

Tags: amazon-web-services, makefile, cygwin, aws-lambda

I am using amazon web services cli. I use a makefile to to build my lambda project and upload it to aws lambda. I am on a windows machine and using powershell to call make.

I try to delete my lambda function with the following lines

```
AWS_PATH = /cygdrive/c/Users/TestBox/AppData/Roaming/Python/Scripts/aws
AWS_WIN_PATH = $(shell cygpath -aw ${AWS_PATH})
AWS_REGION = eu-west-2

lambda_delete:
    $(AWS_WIN_PATH) lambda delete-function --function-name LambdaTest --region $(AWS_REGION) --debug
```

I get this error..

NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".

Running aws configure list prints out a valid default profile.

I think the problem is because i am using gnu make installed by cygwin on a windows machine. Using powershell to call make.

So the path to credentials looks like this "cygdrive/c/users/testbox/.aws/credentials" instead "c:\users\testbox.aws\credentials", when ~/.aws/credentials is evaluated by aws. I think :)

I had the same problem with the path to aws itself and had to use $(shell cygpath -aw ${AWS_PATH}) to convert it to a path windows python could use.

Is there any way to pass the credentials directly to the lambda delete-function or indirectly through a path to a file? I cant seem to think of a way because the code that searches for the credentials is internal to botocore.

Is there a way around this that you know off?

Comment: GNU make's default shell is /bin/sh, "If this variable is not set in your makefile, the program /bin/sh is used as the shell." https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Choosing-the-Shell.html

Comment: @strongjz can you explain the solution in a bit more detail?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Alternative solution, consider using [AWS SAM templates](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model)

Use AWS SAM templates to deploy your Lambda functions and AWS resources using CloudFormation.

- Edit your SAM template and define your AWS resources. For example, define Lambda functions/path to your code.
- `aws cloudformation package` to package and upload your local code to S3.
- `aws cloudformation deploy` to provision and update AWS resources with the updated code on S3.

This would work in CMD/Powershell without the `make` hassle. You will also have the benefit of having your resources versioned as code and you won't need to worry about tracking or adding new AWS APIs in your make file.

More complex serverless frameworks for reference:

- AWS Chalice https://github.com/aws/chalice
- Django/Flask + Lambda https://github.com/Miserlou/Zappa
- Cross cloud serverless solution https://github.com/serverless/serverless

Comment: Ah ok, its my tech stack. Mixing cygwin and windows can cause issues. i was following a youtube video tutorial on lambdas but i think the person doing it was is on a linux/mac machine. I will try your solution out and see if it works for me and then mark your answer.

Comment: Looking into apex and AWS SAM for deployment of my lambdas now. Still probably use make file for building and preparing my lambda package. Thanks.